# Combo Box Query to show all records

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have multiple combo-boxes with a query that filters one after the other (drill-down) and the last combo-box selection shows the records via subform-query.

My concern is if I leave any combo-box without selection (blank) the the result is **blank**. How do I change the default to `*` instead of blank?

I followed other recommendation from StackOverflow without success.
I've tried to set the combo-box value to `Like "*"` and `like <combo-box> & "*"`, it does not work.

All suggestions are really appreciated.

In my code, I am checking if combo-box is null, then `*` else use combo-box selection:

In my Query:

```
Field = Customer
Table = tblCustomer
Criteria = IIf(IsNull([Forms]![frmRSC]![cboCustomer]),[Forms]![frmRSC]![cboCustomer] Like "*",[Forms]![frmRSC]![cboCustomer])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is using the control value like a query field in criteria:

```vb
WHERE (Customer = [Forms]![frmRSC]![cboCustomer] OR [Forms]![frmRSC]![cboCustomer] IS NULL)
```

Expression is true if`[Forms]![frmRSC]![cboCustomer]`is Null (the value of empty ComboBox).

See [Show All Records if Form Control is Left Empty](https://www.devhut.net/2016/06/10/ms-access-show-all-records-if-form-control-is-left-empty/)